# Program to take a number from 0 to 9 as input

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to make a function that requests a number from 0 to 9 to the user and that is robust. I've been looking at code to guide me and most fail to find any of these situations, usually due to the use of `cin`:

1. If the user enters spaces before or after the number, the entry is valid
2. If you end the input (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in Windows; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on most Unix) an infinite cycle is produced
3. If the user typed 2ff the entry is valid
4. The entry is waiting for us to type something because of a line jump

I've made the following code and I don't think it fails with its purpose. I would like to know your opinion and if you believe in any case where it could fail or if I can improve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int input_number()
{

    string data = "";
    while (true)
    {

        cout << "Input: ";
        if (!getline(cin, data))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (data.length() != 1 || isspace(data[0]))
        {
            cerr << "Invalid number, try again!" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        try
        {
            return stoi(data);
        }
        catch (const exception &e)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid number, try again!" << endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << input_number() << endl;
}
```

Comment: my c++ is not that strong but in other languages i might check for regex '^\d$' instead of your length and whitespace check. also this would mean you shouldn't have to catch an exception.

Comment: `if (data.length() == 1 && isnum(data[0])) return data[0] - '0';`

Answer (score 1):

This can be rewritten using regular expression `\s*(\d)\D*` (zero or more whitespace characters, a single digit, zero or more non digit characters. If I understand correctly, heading and trailing spaces are ok, `2ff` is ok but `ff2` is not ok and `23` is not ok either.

```
int input_number() {
  static const std::regex valid_number("\\s*(\\d)\\D*");
  string data;
  std::smatch matches;
  while (true) {
    cout << "Input: ";
    if (getline(cin, data) && 
          std::regex_match(data, matches, valid_number)) {
        return stoi(matches[1]);
    }
    cerr << "Invalid number, try again!" << endl;
  }
}
```

The exception on parsing should never be thrown, regular expression takes care to feed only valid number as the input. The initial version contained try/catch construct to catch it anyway and assert false but this idea is probably over-engineering.

Comment: Don't catch and `assert(false)`, it adds four lines of code just to get a slightly better error message with debug builds. And when creating a release build with `-DNDEBUG` enabled, the `assert()` becomes a NOP, which means a potential error will then be ignored.

Comment: Sometimes is the art to decide how much is too much. I have removed the try/catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Please don't do that.  Use the full names, or (if you must) just import only the names you need, and only into the smallest reasonable scope.

> ```
> int input_number()
> ```

It would be easier to <s>use</s>**test** this code if we could pass a stream to read from:

```
int input_number(std::istream& input = std::cin)
```

> ```
>     std::isspace(data[0])
> ```

Missing header `<cctype>`.

> ```
>     catch (const std::exception& e)
> ```

That's a very broad catch - we could reduce to `std::logic_error` to catch everything we expect from `std::stoi()`.

> ```
>         std::cin.clear();
> ```

Not sure what that's doing there - this will be a no-op given that we don't reach this statement if `!cin` (because we return after calling `std::getline()`).

---

I wonder if the behaviour is exactly what we want.  I think it's perhaps over-strict.  If I input  `3`, I would expect that to count as entering a single-digit number, despite the extra space character.  What about if I enter `01`?  Surely that's a number in the range 0-9?

I think that returning -1 on error is a poor choice compared to throwing an exception.  It's much too easy to forget to handle return values, especially for relatively uncommon events.

I think that a better interface is described by these tests:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <sstream>
TEST(input_number, empty)
{
    std::istringstream in{""};
    EXPECT_THROW(input_number(in), std::ios_base::failure);
}

TEST(input_number, alphabetic)
{
    std::istringstream in{"a"};
    EXPECT_THROW(input_number(in), std::ios_base::failure);
}

TEST(input_number, too_small)
{
    std::istringstream in{"-1"};
    EXPECT_THROW(input_number(in), std::ios_base::failure);
}

TEST(input_number, small)
{
    std::istringstream in{"0"};
    EXPECT_EQ(input_number(in), 0);
}

TEST(input_number, big)
{
    std::istringstream in{"9"};
    EXPECT_EQ(input_number(in), 9);
}

TEST(input_number, too_big)
{
    std::istringstream in{"10"};
    EXPECT_THROW(input_number(in), std::ios_base::failure);
}



TEST(input_number, trailing_alpha)
{
    std::istringstream in{"2ff"};
    EXPECT_THROW(input_number(in), std::ios_base::failure);
}

TEST(input_number, leading_zeros)
{
    std::istringstream in{"007"};
    EXPECT_EQ(input_number(in), 7);
}

TEST(input_number, leading_spaces)
{
    std::istringstream in{"  3"};
    EXPECT_EQ(input_number(in), 3);
}


TEST(input_number, empty_then_valid)
{
    std::istringstream in{"\n3"};
    EXPECT_EQ(input_number(in), 3);
}

TEST(input_number, alpha_then_valid)
{
    std::istringstream in{"foo\n3"};
    EXPECT_EQ(input_number(in), 3);
}
```

Here's a small modification to the code that acts that way:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

int input_number(std::istream& input = std::cin)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Input: " << std::flush;
        std::string data;
        if (!std::getline(input, data))
        {
            throw std::ios_base::failure("Cannot read input stream");
        }
        try
        {
            std::size_t end_pos;
            auto i = std::stoi(data, &end_pos);
            if (end_pos == data.size() && 0 <= i && i <= 9) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        catch (const std::logic_error&)
        {
        }
        std::cerr << "Invalid number, try again!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

There's more that can be done to improve this.  For example, rather than embedding the range 0-9 within the function, pass the constraints into the function, so we can use it to accept different ranges.  If we pass a callable, then we could even use unlikely constraints, such as requiring an odd number!